# Removing and adding a pivot item in runtime doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

i am trying to add and remove a pivot item at runtime but it does not cause the layout to repaint itself so the removed pivot item still shows. If i add or remove a pivot item in the method OnNavigatedTo, it works. But i need this when the page is already "there", not in OnNavigatedTo. Any suggestions?

Best
Yimei

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to Add and Remove Pivot Items dynamically using the following code :-

```
    private void AddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPivot.Items.Add(new PivotItem() { Header = "New Item" });
    }

    private void RemoveItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPivot.Items.RemoveAt(MyPivot.Items.Count - 1);
    }
```

How are you adding the new Pivot Items?

Thanks

Paul Diston

Comment: hi, i use the same method but the pivot item that should be removed stays on the screen and if clicked on, the app would crash.